# It looks like somebody is using my Mac OS X server to brute force attack another server which is LDAP. What can I do to stop it?

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, mac-osx-server, hacking, directory-services

An LDAP server on another is reporting an unusually large number of attempts to read the LDAP directory and attempting a number of users, all of which look like hacking attempts to read user/password information. These happen every minute. It reports that the originating IP is a Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger Server which is a file server on the network for iMacs.

When I run `lsof -i:ldap +c 0` on the Mac server, it returns

```
COMMAND          PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
DirectoryService  60 root   11u  IPv4 0x38de228      0t0  TCP mymacserver.com:50106->myldapserver.com:ldap (ESTABLISHED)
```

Running `ps -Aj` gives

```
USER PID PPID PGID    SESS JOBC STAT TT     TIME COMMAND
[...]
root  60    1   60 290c7e4    0 Ss   ??  0:19.00 /usr/sbin/DirectoryService
```

Running `cat /Library/Logs/DirectoryService/DirectoryService.server.log` gives

```
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - DirectoryService 2.1 (v353.6) starting up...
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Initializing TCP ...
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin <Configure>, Version <1.7>, processed successfully.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin <NetInfo>, Version <1.7.4>, processed successfully.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin <LDAPv3>, Version <1.7.4>, processed successfully.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin <Search>, Version <1.7>, processed successfully.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "Active Directory", Version "1.5.8", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "AppleTalk", Version "1.3", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "Bonjour", Version "1.3", loaded successfully.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "BSD", Version "1.2.2", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "PasswordServer", Version "3.1.2", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "SLP", Version "1.3.1", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plugin "SMB", Version "1.3", is set to load lazily.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Registered node /Configure
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Registered node /Search
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plug-in Configure state is now active.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Registered node /Search/Contacts
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Registered node /Search/Network
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plug-in Bonjour state is now active.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plug-in Search state is now active.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plug-in LDAPv3 state is now active.
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Registered node /NetInfo/DefaultLocalNode
2012-02-15 15:01:29 EST - Plug-in NetInfo state is now active.
2012-02-15 15:01:32 EST - Network transition occurred.
2012-02-15 15:01:35 EST - Registered Locally Hosted Node /NetInfo/DefaultLocalNode
2012-02-15 15:01:41 EST - Network transition occurred.
2012-02-15 15:01:41 EST - Network transition occurred.
2012-02-15 15:01:41 EST - Network transition occurred.
```

(The time is when the server was rebooted several hours ago.) This has been going on for several days.

Is there a way to see what is calling the DirectoryService every minute?

I cannot use `netstat -p`, since Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger does not support the `-p` option.

I need to disable this malicious script, but I cannot disable the LDAP client completely, as users rely on this server for file storage and user ids.

**EDIT:**

I ran `sudo killall -USR1 DirectoryService` to enable to debug log, and it seems that `memberd` and `lookupd` are calling DirectoryService.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Comment: lookupd and memberd are other parts of OS X's directory service (user & group etc lookup) system, not the ultimate source of the queries.  You can enable debug logging for lookupd (see [TN2124](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECLOOKUPD)), but usually lookup calls go to DirectoryService first and then it'll (sometimes) pass them on to lookupd.  I'd check the DS log again for queries coming in from somewhere else.

Comment: Another thing occurred to me: memberd's job is to calculate group membership; is it possible it's looking up lots of user records as part of an attempt to do something like list all members of some group?

Comment: Just a gut feeling but this doesn't *feel* like a compromise.  It feels like a misconfuguration.  As Gordon said, try to correlate the lookups with some other event such as a user accessing a file or logging in.

Comment: From much painful experience manually getting Linux to authenticate to Active Directory, this could very well be a misconfiguration or something broken by a vendor.  For instance, the difference in number of LDAP lookups when performing 'ls' versus 'ls -latr' is quite staggering.  ls would return quick, ls -latr would take forever for each call to ActiveDirectory to time out.

Answer (score 1):

The usual studd:

- Pull server from network.
- Totally wipe it, start reinstalling from known safe sources (OS discs)
- Reinstall everything.
- Make sure you dont makemistakes and patche everything up.
- Restore data from backup.

it is not "a script", you dont know what other stuff a hacker may have installed.